# Помогите изменить стиль DatePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Хочу изменить стиль DatePicker под стиль приложения. Приложение выполнено в Fluent дизайне а.к.а Windows 11. Т.е. в приложение скруглены все углы на всех элементах, изменены цвета и убраны рамки.

Хочу теперь тоже самое сделать для элемента DatePicker, но никак не могу разобрать как изменить его шаблон.

В интернете ничего кроме создания нового кастомного элемента DatePicker не нашел (*возможно плохо искал)*. Хотелось бы просто изменить стиль шаблона уже существующего стандартного DatePicker т.к. его функциональная часть полностью устраивает в отличии от дизайна.

Comment: Добавляем пустой, без стилей контрол, жмем в окне предпросмотра ПКМ - Шаблон - Править копию, выбираем куда надо создавать, соглашаемся со всем, готово, студия сгенерировала полную копию дефолтного шаблона, со всем необходимым, правим на свой вкус и цвет. Также открываем любимый поисковик, пишем там `wpf DatePicker style`, первой ссылкой видим [официальную документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/datepicker-styles-and-templates), где объясняют подробно каждую часть шаблона.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо. Я настроил текстовое поле и кнопку DatePicker'а по стилю как мне нужно. Но как настроить по стилю сам календарь-пикер? Я посмотрел документацию и там тот же пример из шаблона с элементом <popup>. Как я понял это и есть всплывающий календарь-пикер. Как в нем хотябы углы закруглить?